# Manually adding select options does not work correctly every time, and even if it did, the second atempt is always a failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to create a modal with three text_fields, and when submitting, I need to preventDefault on the browser (to not reload the page, in case any data was put beside modal), then send data to the backend through AJAX, and then manually update the select_2 with submitted option.

Changing variables types, splitting .trigger("change") into a new line, or zeroing option object after appending it, doesn't seem to change anything.

```
<div class="sampling-register">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <form>
        <div class="section">
          <div>
            <%= select_tag :client, grouped_options_for_select(@clients),
                           :include_blank => 'Wybierz klienta', class: 'select2_demo_2', required: true %>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#client_modal">
              <%= image_tag 'laboratory/add_circle_blue' %>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="client_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content animated fadeIn">
        <div class="modal-header">Dodaj klienta</div>
        <%= form_for :client, url: clients_path, :html => {:id => "form_add_client"} do |f| %>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= f.hidden_field :laboratory_id, value: current_user.company.laboratory.id %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Nazwa', required: true %>
            <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Adres' %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="discard" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
            <button class="submit">Dodaj</button>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script>
    let form = $("#form_add_client");
    let submitBtn = form.find(".submit");
    let client_select_tag = $("#client");

    form.on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let name = $('#client_name').val();
        let client_address = $('#client_address').val();
        let laboratory_id = $('#client_laboratory_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/clients',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                client: {
                    name: name,
                    address: client_address,
                    laboratory_id: laboratory_id
                },
            }
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    toastr["error"](result.error);
                } else {
                    let option = new Option(result.data.name, "{lab_client_id: " + result.data.id + "}", false, true);
                    client_select_tag.children().eq(2).append(option).trigger('change');
                    $('#client_modal').modal('hide');
                    toastr["success"]("Klient dodany poprawnie");
                }
            })
    })
</script>
```

The problem is, it does works, but then sometimes doesn't (like every third try), and even if it works once, then every other attempt is a failure until I reload the page. After reloading, it seems like a coin throw again.
It does trigger the appended option as selected EVERY time, but actually appending to the select list does not occur so often.

Comment: Did you do a `console.log( result );` in your `.done` function ? It's just a guess since we dont see any backend logic but maybe you get some error  that gets not returned as you expect in your `if(result.error)` condition

Comment: Yes, i tried that. Seems that result is OK (it contains error value only if something actually went wrong). If input data is correct, backend seems to work fine, the data appends in database, and the success toastr pops out, along with the modal going invisible.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what's going on without the actual html. What is `#client`? What's the chance that you could isolate the problem and reproduce the issue so we could try to debug it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added the HTML code that renders before modal.
The controller provides @clients object, that is a hash with two values, separated into optgroups. The second optgroup is where i want my jQuery code to put the "option" object.
I don't really know what can I strip from my code so it still represents same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems that changing

```
client_select_tag.children().eq(2).append(option).trigger('change');
```

into

```
client_select_tag.select2().children().eq(2).append(option).trigger('change');
```

makes the code works